# Compiling Error on NSOutlineView: Semantic Issue 'moveRowAtIndex:toIndex:' is unavailable

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview

When I try to compile the following code,

```
[self.outlineView beginUpdates];
[self.outlineView moveRowAtIndex:row toIndex:targetRow];
[self.outlineView endUpdates];
```

I get the following compiler error:

**Semantic issue 'moveRowAtIndex:toIndex:' is unavailable**

All other operations on NSOutlineView work except for this one.

One thing that is worth noting, is that when XCode autocompletes it shows this with a red line stroke on top of it as if it was deprecated but the documentation says that it is valid.

My project is being built for OSX 10.8 and the documentation says that this is available for OSX 10.7 and newer.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/General/MacOSXLionAPIDiffs/AppKit.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSTableView

I didn't find anything online that pointed me to a solution and I am wondering if anyone has any thoughts on how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

`-moveRowAtIndex:toIndex:` is declared and defined in `NSTableView`. Note that `NSOutlineView` inherits from `NSTableView` but, because of its hierarchical nature, some `NSTableView` methods are not available, which is why you get that compiler error.

You should use `-moveItemAtIndex:inParent:toIndex:inParent:` instead.

Unfortunately, the documentation does not reflect this yet. It’s often useful to browse the header files since they are more accurate declaration-wise and tend to be up-to-date documentation-wise. If you open NSOutlineView.h, you’ll notice that `-moveItemAtIndex:toIndex:` is declared with `UNAVAILABLE_ATTRIBUTE`, which corresponds to `__attribute__((unavailable))`.